# A strange runtime error in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int testMul(int a, int b)
{
    return !a || a * b / a == b;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    while(cin >> a >> b) cout << testMul(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When the input is

> -1 -2147483648

, there is a runtime error.Divided by 0? 
I think it is amazing.

By the way, has anyone concluded a way that can judge if there is a overflow in multiplication?

Comment: if you came up with that input, you already know what the problem is....

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply `-1` and `-2147483648` you get signed overflow, which is an undefined behaviour in C++, the result can be any, up to your computer catching fire. So getting division by zero is actually not that bad of an outcome.